# 500 Internal Server Error - Only for Control Panel

Tags: ee2

There was a 500 error out of no where.

The front end works fine, however, I am not able to login.

Removed the .htaccess file and checked, still no avail.

Help please!

EE 2.11.1
PHP 5.6.13

Comment: It might sound strange, but when I switched the ISP, the 500 server error went away. I am guessing it has something to do with the DNS.

Answer (score 1):

From BoldMinded Support:

**Apr 10, 2016**

> It seems there was a change in EE 2.11 that caused this. CSM was using a method of extending/hijacking a core class to get this to work, which has been fine for the last 6+ years, but no longer works. If you really need to use CSM you’ll need to downgrade to 2.10. Otherwise I suggest just uninstalling it.
>
> I’ll work with EllisLab so I can restore the functionality to CSM, however, I wouldn’t expect anything to happen in the next week or two.
>
> Sorry for the troubles, but I’ll post updates here when I get them.

**Apr 17, 2016**

> You can now download version 2.6 (it is packaged with the EE3 version 3.0.2). If you’re using EE 2.11, which is causing the problem, you will need to make a core hack. See the README file. This change will be in EE 2.12 so you only need to make this hack once.

Link to ticket: https://boldminded.com/support/ticket/1283

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling extensions.
In your config file add:

```
$config['allow_extensions'] = 'n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also individually turn your extension on/off via your installation's DB.

To address the actual issue:
I'm experiencing this same issue today and I've narrowed it down to Custom System Messages.

I'll report back when I find a solution.